# Enumeration for "regular" paragraphs

Tags: enumerate, paragraphs, enumitem

I would like to have enumerated paragraphs using the document's default paragraph layout. Currently, I achieve this using manual enumerations using the code listed below.

How can I get the same result, but automating the enumeration?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

(1) \lipsum[1]

(2) \lipsum[1]

(3) \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean `\begin{enumerate} \item bla \item ble \item blo \end{enumerate}` ?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use enumerate, but make it look like above.

Comment: The I would recommend using the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which is capable of doing this :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much simpler with the use of  `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(1),wide, nosep]

\item \lipsum[1]

\item \lipsum[2]

\item \lipsum[3]

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's easy with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm,itemindent=2\parindent,noitemsep,label=(\arabic*)]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\everypar{\refstepcounter{enumi}(\theenumi) }

 \lipsum[1]

 \lipsum[1]

 \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ability to turn on and off, here is the `enumpars` environment, using the technique of David at [Why does \everypar not work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119758/why-does-everypar-not-work)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{parcount}
\let\oldep\everypar%
\newenvironment{enumpars}
{\newtoks\everypar%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%
\oldep{\the\everypar\stepcounter{parcount}(\theparcount)\ }%
\par}{\let\everypar\oldpars\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{enumpars}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{enumpars}
\end{document}
```