# Paragraph numbering (lineno for paragraphs)

Tags: paragraphs, double-sided, line-numbering

How can I add margin numbering for paragraphs? It should be alternating (left and right) for odd and even pages. So basically like `lineo` with the switch option but for paragraphs instead of lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

Shorter and raw

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{mypara}
\setcounter{mypara}{0}

\begin{document}
  \everypar{\refstepcounter{mypara}
  \ifodd\value{page}
  \marginpar{\themypara}
  \else
  \marginpar{\makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\themypara}}
  \fi}%
  \lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This uses `\everypar` (exploiting David's answer at [Why does \everypar not work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119758/why-does-everypar-not-work)) to make "something" happen every paragraph.  In this case, the "something" that happens is a `\tabto` to the margin, where the paragraph number is laid, followed by a return to the original position.  I use an `everypage` hook to toggle the marginal location with each page.

I wrap it all in an `enumpars` environment, so that you can turn it on and off at will.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabto,everypage}
\def\TabMargLeft{-.5in}
\def\TabMargRight{\dimexpr\textwidth+.5in\relax}
\def\TabMargPos{\TabMargRight}
\AddEverypageHook{\ifdim\TabMargPos=\TabMargLeft\relax%
  \gdef\TabMargPos{\TabMargRight}\else%
  \gdef\TabMargPos{\TabMargLeft}\fi}
\newcounter{parcount}
\let\oldep\everypar%
\newenvironment{enumpars}
{\newtoks\everypar%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%
\oldep{\the\everypar\stepcounter{parcount}%
  \tabto*{\TabMargPos}\makebox[0pt]{(\theparcount)}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}%
\par}{\global\let\everypar\oldep\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{enumpars}
\lipsum[6-8]
\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[9-14]
\end{enumpars}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It says `\let\oldep\everypar` in the beginnig but `\let\everypar\oldpars`  at the end -- is this a typo? Isn't the idea to save whatever it is `\everypar` and reset it to this value after the `enumpars`-environment? Or am I just misunderstanding what you are doing here?

Comment: @Florian Yes, thank you for detecting that typo.  I will fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having an issue with this solution: When I add another evironment, say `\begin{enumerate}` *after* `enumpars` has been used I get "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." Using environments *within* `enumpars` works fine and the paragraphs are even counted properly.

Comment: @Florian Thanks again for noting that.  I had to make the final `\let` of `enumpars` be global in order to reach outside of the environment.  Thus, the closing part of the environment now reads, `{\global\let\everypar\oldep\par}`

Comment: This must be getting on your nerves... But you wouldn't have an idea why `\usepackage[cam, info]{crop}` interferes with the counting, would you?

Comment: @Florian I am sorry, but I have no familiarity with those packages to even have a clue about the adverse interaction.