# crop-package interfering with paragraph counter using everypar

Tags: counters, paragraphs, crop

Steven B. Segletes [has devised a well working way to count paragraphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231857/6819) that doesn't seem to interfere with all the (many) packages that I am using in my book. Apart for one exception: The `crop`-package will count its marks and header-info as paragraphs.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}

\newcounter{parcount}
\let\oldep\everypar%
\newenvironment{enumpars}
{\newtoks\everypar%
\setcounter{parcount}{0}%
\oldep{\the\everypar\stepcounter{parcount}%
    \textbf{(\theparcount)}\qquad}%
\par}{\global\let\everypar\oldep\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{enumpars}

\lipsum[6-8]

\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[9-14]
\end{enumpars}

\end{document}
```

Would there be a way to "shield" `\everypar` perhaps by saving its content before `crop` starts its working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a current LaTeX you can try this. But in a real document there can be more paragraphs appearing in wrong places

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}
\newbool{parabool}

\usepackage[cam,a4,center]{crop}

\newcounter{parcount}

\AddToHook{para/begin}[enumpars]{\ifbool{parabool}{\stepcounter{parcount}\textbf{(\theparcount)}\qquad}{}}

\newenvironment{enumpars}
 {\setcounter{parcount}{0}%
  \booltrue{parabool}\par}
{}

\makeatletter
\preto\CROP@@@marks{\boolfalse{parabool}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{enumpars}

\lipsum[6-8]

\begin{enumpars}
\lipsum[9-14]
\end{enumpars}

\end{document}
```

[image]